# 'FROM' syntax error involved with huge UNION clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

Okay, an ongoing project (in MS ACCESS) I've had is computing the number of each extra 'option' purchased by customers for a car company. To that end, I've created the following query to put every option into one column, and then sum the totals for each option in the next column(edited for readability and anonymity).

```
SELECT a.options, Count(*)
FROM(
SELECT TBL.Des1 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des2 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des3 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des4 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des5 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des6 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des7 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des8 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des9 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des10 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des11 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des12 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des13 AS options FROM TBL) AS a

INTO TBL_OPTION_ALL
GROUP BY a.options;
```

My issue is the error "Syntax error in FROM clause" upon attempt to run. Upon termination of the error prompt, the INTO statement at the bottom is highlighted. Originally, I had seperated each SELECT with parenthesis, but then I got an error of "syntax error from JOIN clause", and found a similar post with the problem, which was fixed by removing parentheses. I also originally had just `(...)a` to create the alias, but I have turned it into `(...) AS a` for this because I am not sure if that method of creating an alias works in Access.

I have a few theories as to where my problem resides (ordered from most likely to least)

1. I am using () when I should be using [], or

   - I am missing parentheses around some of my UNION calls, or
   - I need to organize my parentheses completely differently, and break down the UNIONs as I tried before.
2. It can't handle this many UNIONs. If this is the case, how could I structure this? Would I have to build up multiple queries?

Comment: If you run the subquery (UNION ALLs), does it run without any errors?

Comment: good look, yes it does run without errors, assuming I swap out the placements of FROM TBL and AS options (as I am about to note in an edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax backwards. It's

```
Select <your columns> 
Into <destination table> 
From <source table>
```

So you should have:

```
SELECT a.options, Count(*)
INTO TBL_OPTION_ALL
FROM(
SELECT TBL.Des1 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des2 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des3 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des4 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des5 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des6 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des7 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des8 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des9 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des10 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des11 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des12 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des13 AS options FROM TBL) AS a
GROUP BY a.options;
```

Comment: That is it. Thanks. I got so caught up on the multiple SELECT phrases that I totally ignored ordering.

Answer (score 4):

Try the below code, you aliased the table not the field.

```
SELECT a.options, Count(*)
FROM(
SELECT TBL.Des1  AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des2 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des3  AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des4 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des5  AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des6  AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des7 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des8 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des9 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des10 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des11 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des12  AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des13  AS optionsFROM TBL) AS a

INTO TBL_OPTION_ALL
GROUP BY a.options;
```

Comment: I swapped around the AS and FROM portions of the subquery, but I am still getting the same error on run attempt. The subquery will run without errors, but does not work inside the FROM clause.

Comment: I removed the `AS a` portion, but it did not help the error throw.

Comment: Try removing the AS options from all of the unions except the first one. And you need the "AS a" part of the query that is the derived table name.

Comment: done, does not change FROM error, and subquery still runs fine on its own.

Comment: Does it run if you remove the INTO TBL_OPTION_ALL clause?

Comment: My issue was actually the ordering of `SELECT, FROM, INTO` where it should have `SELECT, INTO, FROM` Thank you for your help, though.

Answer (score 1):

"AS options" needs to be after the column name in your sub queries, not after the table name.

**UPDATE**

Try this:

```
SELECT a.options, Count(*)
INTO TBL_OPTION_ALL
FROM(
SELECT TBL.Des1 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des2 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des3 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des4 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des5 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des6 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des7 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des8 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des9 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des10 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des11 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des12 AS options FROM TBL UNION ALL
SELECT TBL.Des13 AS options FROM TBL) AS a
GROUP BY a.options;
```

Comment: I took this action, but it did not fix the overall problem. It certainly makes it so that the subquery actually does what I want, but it doesn't help with the syntax error within the FROM statement.

Comment: You also need to add a from clause to the sub query after the final UNION ALL.

Comment: correct, the clause was missing from the code I uploaded, but I double-checked and it is proper in Access. The `FROM` clause is not missing there.

Comment: I think I have got it. Remove the into statement from where it is and insert a line at the top: "Insert Into TBL_OPTION_ALL(col_name)", obviously replace col_name with the actual column name. Also, just to check does the TBL_OPTION_ALL table already exist or are you trying to create it with this statement? If you are trying to create the table we will need to amend the syntax slightly.

Comment: I am creating this table, not appending in this code. Does that mean I just lose the "INSERT" statement?

Comment: You were correct in thinking this way, I had the syntax backwards. That was the issue.

Comment: In that case you do need the into syntax, but before the first from clause. I will update my original answer with what is hopefully the final code.