# SQL Union ALL "Syntax Eror in From Clause"

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm struggling with MS Access 2010 SQL.  Can anyone see why the following SQL statement would produce a "Syntax Error in FROM clause?"

```
INSERT INTO Attendance 
SELECT [AttendanceData].Student, [AttendanceData].[10/1/2015] AS AttendValue,
"10/1/15" AS AttendDate
FROM [AttendanceData]
UNION ALL 
SELECT [AttendanceData].Student, [AttendanceData].[10/2/2015] AS AttendValue, 
"10/2/15" As AttendDate
FROM [AttendanceData];
```

Individual statements work fine, but when combined with UNION ALL, I receive the

> Syntax Error in FROM Clause."

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: what are the columns in `Attendance` table?

Comment: Please see the ['FROM' syntax error involved with huge UNION clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284174/from-syntax-error-involved-with-huge-union-clause)

Comment: And do use a proper string expression for your date value: `#2015/10/2# As AttendDate`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something like that:

```
INSERT INTO Attendance
SELECT R.Student, R.AttendValue, R.AttendDate
FROM
(
  (SELECT [AttendanceData].Student, [AttendanceData].[10/1/2015] AS AttendValue,
   "10/1/15" AS AttendDate
    FROM [AttendanceData] )

  UNION ALL 

 (SELECT [AttendanceData].Student, [AttendanceData].[10/2/2015] AS AttendValue, 
  "10/2/15" As AttendDate
   FROM [AttendanceData])
) AS R
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access Jet/ACE SQL, you cannot use a union query **directly** in an append query. You will see the query debugger highlights the `UNION ALL` statement.

Save union query separately as stored query object and then use that in the `SELECT` statement of append query.

```
INSERT INTO Attendance 
SELECT * FROM UnionAttendance
```

Alternatively, you can use a derived table:

```
INSERT INTO Attendance 
SELECT *
FROM ( 
     SELECT [AttendanceData].Student, [AttendanceData].[10/1/2015] AS AttendValue,
     "10/1/15" AS AttendDate
     FROM [AttendanceData]
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT [AttendanceData].Student, [AttendanceData].[10/2/2015] AS  AttendValue, 
     "10/2/15" As AttendDate
     FROM [AttendanceData]
);
```